# Can a Shi'ite girl do tayammum over makeup?

Tags: shiism, wudu, tayammum

According to Shi'ite jurisprudence, can a girl do tayammum over makeup? Sometimes girls fall into this type of situation.. what to do then?

Comment: @goldPseudo I didn't know "Grand Ayatollah Sistani" is a Shia person, until your edit. That girl wasn't a shia girl per se, and was asking a general rule, and which needed no narrowing down to Shia school although the scholar was a Shia who gave the ruling.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser The answer *does not provide* a "general ruling"; if any future visitors come seeking an answer to whether a girl can do tayammum over makeup, they still need to know that this question does (or does not) answer *their* question.  As is, this question and accepted answer *are only useful to Shi'ites*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**. According to Grand Ayatollah Sistani's Fatwa, when performing Tayammum, You should remove any obstruction which might be on your forehead, palms and on the back of your hands. Anything stuck on the skin of these parts should be removed.

**2**. The onus is on followers to specify Whether something is obstruction or not.

However putting on make-up in ceremonies, parties and weddings, no matter how long they take, cannot be an acceptable excuse for leaving out Wudhu. There are two ways in such situations:

1. One can perform Wudhu before wearing make-up and try to stay in the state of Taharat until she has performed her prayer at the prescribed time.
2. One should take off her make-up so that she can perform Wudhu for prayers.